# Django Queryset as a List

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a Django queryset filter that will check a list on the left-hand side against a list on the right-hand side of the equation and filter the response if any item from the right-hand list appears in the left-hand list.

The classes:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Site(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()

class StaffSiteAff(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site')
    staff = models.ForeignKey('Staff')
```

My filter will take the current staff as a parameter and return all staff who have a site that the current staff also has.  Both staff will likely have multiple sites.  The difficulty stems from comparing a list using django "left-hand" field searching.  Is there a way to do this?  Do I need to use a custom manager?

Comment: Whats the relation between `Staff` and `UserSiteAff` and how do I know if a staff has `UserSiteAff`?

Comment: so you want to get `UserSiteAff` objects based on a staff list you have?

Comment: This would return `staff` objects only if any one of 'their' sites matches any one of 'my' sites.  I changed the junction table to `StaffSiteAff` to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have staffs

```
# 1. Mike
# 2. John
# 3. Alex
```

Lets say we have Sites

```
# 1. Site A
# 2. Site B
# 3. Site C
# 4. Site D
```

Lets say we have these relations

```
# Site A -- Alex
# Site D -- Alex
# Site C -- John
# Site B -- Mike
# Site A -- Mike
```

Your list

```
# [Site A, Site B]
```

I should get a list of Staffs [Alex, Mike]

```
mylist = Site.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2])
>> [<Site: Site A>, <Site: Site B>]

# Gettings StaffSiteAff objects related
StaffSiteAff.objects.filter(site__in=mylist)
>> [<StaffSiteAff: Site A -- Mike>, <StaffSiteAff: Site A -- Alex>, <StaffSiteAff: Site B -- Mike>]

# get only staffs from the last query
StaffSiteAff.objects.filter(site__in=mylist).values("staff")
>> [{'staff': 1}, {'staff': 3}, {'staff': 1}]

# get Staff using the last query
Staff.objects.filter(id__in=StaffSiteAff.objects.filter(site__in=mylist).values("staff"))
>> [<Staff: Mike>, <Staff: Alex>]
```

---

The above is an explanation of all steps. However, you can reach this by accessing the FK relation

```
>>> mylist
[<Site: Site A>, <Site: Site B>]
>>> Staff.objects.filter(staffsiteaff__site__id__in=mylist).distinct()
[<Staff: Mike>, <Staff: Alex>]
```